# Multi column ListView in WPF without using GridView

Tags: wpf, xaml, listview

I'm trying to make a two-column ListView. I'd like to avoid putting a GridView inside it because the design specs I'm matching are very simplistic. I can get the exact behavior that I want with an ItemsControl:

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"     Grid.Column="0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Value}"   Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

This separates the item properties nicely between the two halves of the available space. However, a ListView with identical templates displays the properties right next to each other with no separation. Is there a way I can achieve the desired behavior in a ListView without a GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `ItemsControl` try setting the `ItemContainerStyle` of the `ItemsControl` to stretch the children horizontally:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
```

For `ListView` try setting the `ItemContainerStyle` of the `ListView` to stretch the children horizontally:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Comment: Mind you, this is about making it happen on a ListView and _not_ an ItemsControl. Your answer led me in the right direction, though. Setting Horizontal_Content_Alignment to Stretch fixed it.